# Assign two different attributes of two different selectors for the same value in one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in jQuery

```
var TotalPrice = 23;

$('#prv-selected-case-price').text($(TotalPrice).text());
$('input[name="total-price"]').val($(TotalPrice).text());
```

They feel very equivalent and repetitive, one adds the value of one variable into an HTML tag and the other as a value in another tag. Can this be done in one line?

```
id.text and input.val = TotalPrice.text?
```

Comment: Apart from storing `$(TotalPrice).text()` in a variable and using this variable, I don't see how you can shorten your code further.

Comment: Here you have two different types of attributes how could you join them in one line?

Comment: If you want to be perverse you can try `$('#prv-selected-case-price')[0].innerText = 
$('input[name="total-price"]')[0].value=$(TotalPrice).text();`

Comment: You updated your question - `$(23).text()` does not make any sense - perhaps you meant `var TotalPrice = 23; $('#prv-selected-case-price')[0].innerText = $('input[name="total-price"]')[0].value=TotalPrice;`

Comment: @mplungjan yeah this one is pretty perverse :D

Comment: IMO it will be better to keep it simple stupid for the clarity...

Comment: Other than for purely educational reasons, why would you want to do this?  (as in, what reason do you have, not as in "why oh why oh why")

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to - it is not recommended for clarity reasons, but yes you can. Do at least save the value first

```
var totalPrice = $("#TotalPrice").text(); // assuming <span id="TotalPrice">23</span>

$('#prv-selected-case-price')[0].innerText = 
  $('input[name="total-price"]')[0].value=totalPrice;
```

If you MUST nest, make it clear:

```
$('#prv-selected-case-price').text(
   $('input[name="total-price"]').val(totalPrice).val()
);
```

Or without jQuery, assuming only one total-price input:

```
var totalPrice = document.querySelector("#TotalPrice").textContent;

document.querySelector('#prv-selected-case-price').innerText = 
  document.querySelector('input[name="total-price"]').value=totalPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
var TotalPrice = "#myEle";

$('#prv-selected-case-price').text($('input[name="total-price"]').val($(TotalPrice).text()).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write in one line, you can write :

```
$('#prv-selected-case-price').text($('input[name="total-price"]').val(TotalPrice).val());
```

Comment: I was thinking something about this. Is this a bad solution?